# Proving $(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+...+(2n)^2= \frac{n(2n+1)(7n+1)}{6}$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

My question: $(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2+...+(2n)^2= \frac{n(2n+1)(7n+1)}{6}$

My workings

1. LHS=$2^2$ =$4$ RHS= $\frac{24}{6} =4 $
2. $(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+(k+3)^2+...+(2k)^2= \frac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6}$
3. LHS (subsituting $n= k+1$)----> $(k+2)^2+(k+3)^2+(k+4)^2+...+(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2$

Now, this is where my problem has started. When I substitute $n=k+1$ in the third step, I do not have the $(k+1)^2$ anymore. So I cannot use the statement in second step. So my question is what should i do next?

Comment: $2(k+1)=2k+2{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown uh? sorry can you please provide some explanation please? Thank you.

Comment: @Tfue the last term in 3) must be $(2k+2)^2$ (not $(2k+1)^2$).

Comment: @drhab why can you please give me some explantions? sorry and thank you.

Comment: If you substitute $n=k+1$ in $(n+1)^2+\cdots+(2n)^2$ then you get $((k+1)+1)^2+\cdots(2(k+1))^2=(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k+2)^2$.

Comment: @drhab sorry my question should be how can you get $(2k+1)^2$ <------ i got this accidentally.

Comment: If $f(n)=\frac16n(2n+1)(7n+1)$ then on base of $(k+1)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2=f(k)$ you must prove that $(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k+2)^2=f(k+1)$. That comes to proving that $f(k)+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2=f(k+1)$. Do you understand? I don't understand your "...my question should be how can you get $(2k+1)^2$"

Comment: @drhab sorry again for troubling you, in general how do you obtain $(2k+1)^2$ and $-(k+1)^2$ i do get that i need to prove LHS =RHS thank you

Comment: Let me try an example: $k=2$. Substituting in $(k+1)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2$ gives $3^2+4^2$, right. Substituting $3$ (one more than $2$) gives $4^2+5^2+6^2=[3^2+4^2]+[5^2+6^2-3^2]$. So actually $f(3)=f(2)+[5^2+6^2-3^2]$. In general that gives $f(k+1)=f(k)+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2nd tough-degree exercise in induction. Observe that **both** the first and last elements change, so if $\;k=n\;$ we get

$$(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+\ldots+(2n)^2=\frac{n(2n+1)(7n+1)}6\;\;(**)$$

then for $\;k=n+1\;$ we get

$$(n+1+1)^2+(n+3)^2+\ldots+(2n)^2+(2n+1)^2+\overbrace{(2n+2)^2}^{=(2(n+1))^2}=\frac{(n+1)(2n+3)(7n+8)}6$$

Now, we prove the last one assuming the first one. Developing left side:

$$(n+2)^2+\ldots+(2n)^2+(2n+1)^2+(2n+2)^2=(n+1)^2+\ldots+(2n+2)^2-(n+1)^2=$$

$$=(n+1)^2+\ldots+(2n)^2+(2n+1)^2+(2n+2)^2-(n+1)^2\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=$$

$$=\frac{n(2n+1)(7n+1)}6+(2n+1)^2+4(n+1)^2-(n+1)^2=$$

$$=\frac{n(2n+1)(7n+1)}6+(2n+1)^2+3(n+1)^2=\frac{(2n+1)\left[n(7n+1)+12n+6\right]+18(n+1)^2}6=$$

$$=\frac{(2n+1)(7n^2+13n+6)+18n^2+36n+18}6=\frac{(n+1)(2n+3)(7n+8)}6$$

The last equality you can prove it opening parentheses and equating coefficients, or showing the left side has as roots $\;-1,\,-3/2,\,-8/7\;$

**Alternative way to prove**:

$$(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+\ldots+(n+n)^2=$$

$$=n^2+\ldots+n^2+2n+4n+\ldots+2nn+1+2^2+\ldots+n^2=$$

$$n\cdot n^2+2(1+2+\ldots+n)n+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=$$

$$=n^3+n^2(n+1)+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=\ldots$$

Comment: Wow thanks for this detailed solution! However i still have a every beginnernish question, why did you add $(2n+2)^2$?(in the  first line for $k=n+1$ Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Because the rule is: "Begin with some natural number $\;n\;$ when one is added, and end with twice that number $\;n\;$ "... Thus, when in the inductive step with begin with $\;n+1\;$ and add one to it, we must end with $\;2(n+1)\;$ ...But we sum **consecutive naturals**, so if the last one in the first step is $\;(2n)^2\;$ , the last one in the ind. step is $\;(2(n+1))^2\;$ , and there are **two** consecutive integers there: $\;(2n)^2+\color{red}{(2n+1)^2}+\color{red}{(2n+2)^2}\;$ ...This last addend is just $\;2n+2=2(n+1)\;$ ...the first one times two! (and all squared, of course)

Comment: Sorry sir i meant to write how did you obtain $(2n+1)^2$ which this i accidentally obtained. I do get the $(2n+2)^2$ part now thank you.

Comment: sorry sir i could not understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your third step is wrong. What is to be proven is the following on substituting n = k+1,$$(k+2)^2+(k+3)^2+...+(2k+2)^2 = \frac{(k+1)(2k+3)(7k+8)}{6}$$.
We know the result for $(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+...+(2k)^2$, substitute that here, you'll get,$$LHS = \frac{(k)(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6} + (2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2$$
$$ = \frac{(k+1)(2k+3)(7k+8)}{6}$$

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out mistakes and presenting a solution! However i still have a question. Seeing that i accidentally obtained $(2k+1)^2$ which i meant to write $(2k+2)^2$. Can you please explain ton me how did you get $(2k+1)^2$ and $-(k+1)^2$

Comment: This is how we use induction, we use the induction hypothesis in the induction step for the terms which are common and solve for the rest to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the step for $n=k$ $\:$For

$n=k+1$ $(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k+2)^2=\dfrac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6}-(k+1)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2$ $=\dfrac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6}+3(k+1)^2+(2k+1)^2=\dfrac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6}+7k^2+10k+4=\dfrac{(k+1)(2k+3)(7k+8)}{6}$

Comment: Thanks for answering! However i still have a question how did you get $-(k+1)^2$ and the $(2k+1)^2$

Comment: $(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2=\dfrac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}{6}-(k+1)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2=(k+2)^2\cdots+(2k)^2$ which you can see from $n=k$

Comment: When you substitute $n=k+1$ in $(2k)^2$ we get $(2k+2)^2$. Hence the sum for $n=k+1$ is $(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2$.

Comment: Can't i just do $(k+2)^2+...+(2k)^2+(2k+2)^2$

Comment: No. Just put some values for $k$ to get clarity

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:

$$(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k+2)^2=$$$$\left[(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2\right]+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2=$$$$f(k)+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2-(k+1)^2$$

where $f(k)$ denotes the RHS of 2).

If the equality indeed holds then the outcome must be $f(k+1)$ and that can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

$(k+2)^2+\dots+(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2=\frac{k(2k+1)(7k+1)}6-(k+1)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2=\frac{k(14k^2+9k+1)+6(7k^2+10k+4)}6=\frac{(k+1)(2k+3)(7k+8)}6$.

Comment: Hey thanks can you please explain how did you get $(2k+1)^2$ thank you.

Comment: You need all of the $(k+2)^2$ through $(2k+2)^2$.